# remove method help java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, iterator

I am currently working on a project where I have created an Appointment superclass, with a Daily, Monthly, and Yearly subclass. I also created a Calendar class that has an ArrayList that contains Appointment objects that are dates. In the Calendar class I have an add(), remove(), and toString() methods. The
problem I need advice on is the remove() method. In my tester class when I call upon remove() to remove a certain date, once it finds the date it removes everything in the ArrayList afterwards. How can I fix this so it only removes the particular date I want?

Here is my tester class:

```
/**
 * Demonstration of the Calendar and Appointment classes
 */
public class AppointmentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

        calendar.add(new Daily(2000, 8, 13, "Brush your teeth."));
        calendar.add(new Monthly(2003, 5, 20, "Visit grandma."));
        calendar.add(new OneTime(2004, 11, 2, "Dentist appointment."));
        calendar.add(new OneTime(2004, 10, 31, "Trick or Treat."));
        calendar.add(new Monthly(2004, 11, 2, "Dentist appointment."));
        calendar.add(new OneTime(2004, 11, 2, "Dentist appointment."));


        System.out.println("Before removal of appointment: " + "\n" + calendar);
        calendar.remove(2004, 11, 2);
        //note that the daily appointment is removed because it occurs on
        //11/2/2004 (as well as many other days).  
        System.out.println("After removal of 11/2/2004 " + "\n" + calendar);
    }
}
```

This is my remove() method:

```
public class Calendar 
{
    private ArrayList<Appointment> calendar = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public void remove(int year, int month, int day)
    {   
        //iterate through ArrayList
        for(Iterator<Appointment> i = calendar.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        {  
            Appointment date = i.next(); 
            if(date.occursOn(year, month, day))
            //if the element occurs on the input then remove that element
            {
                i.remove(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My results:

```
 Before removal of appointment: 
 [2000/8/13: Brush your teeth., 
  2003/5/20: Visit grandma., 
  2004/11/2: Dentist appointment., 
  2004/10/31: Trick or Treat., 
  2004/11/2: Dentist appointment., 
  2004/11/2: Dentist appointment.]

 After removal of 11/2/2004 
 [2000/8/13: Brush your teeth., 
  2003/5/20: Visit grandma.]
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything but you should avoid naming your classes like classes which already exist in Java. For instance instead of Calendar consider something more like MyCalendar to not confuse it with `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: With only the code shown here, I assume there is a logical mistake in the `occursOn` function. For example, if it sees a matching year and returns true too quickly it would produce what we see here.